# Error handling in Cross Apply statements

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Cross Apply feature to create formula (on-the-fly) fields in my SQL statement. The issue is that I don't want the entire query to blow up because the formula expression has run time errors.

I am interested to learn what ideas could be used to control the Query's fate.
See the below example:

```
select T1.SubTotal,
   T2.Tax,
   T2.Tax + T1.SubTotal as Total,
   T2.LeftSide, T2.D
from Invoice as I
 cross apply (select (I.UnitPrice * I.Quantity)/NumberOfMonth) as T1(SubTotal)
 cross apply (select T1.SubTotal * (1 - 0.13)) as T2(Tax)
 cross apply (select Left(Field1,SampleCount)) as T2(LeftSide)
 cross apply (select DATEFROMPARTS(2014, Month(CreatedDate)+10, 29)) as T2(Date)
```

For example when NumberOfMonth is zero, or when the value of Field1 is "aaa" and SampleCount turns out to be "-10", or when the Month + 10 make the Date field invalid causing the query to blow up.

**I know one could write extra code to check using CASE statement. I am interested to learn if there are other control techniques.**

**What I am looking for is solution that provide the same benefits that TRY CATCH statement would provide in Stored Procedures. Regardless of what the Cross Apply expression is, if it encounters runtime error, I would be able to catch it and handle the error myself.**

I'd rather would like to control such scenarios and return #Error# or some other pre-define value indicating the Formula encountered a runtime error.
Sample Result-set:

```
SubTotal   Tax  Total  LeftSide  Date
----------------------------------------
2333       234  2455   a         $Error$
3454       122  3565   $Error$   2014-02-12
$Error$    0    0      aa        2014-09-11
```

UPDATE:
I am down the path of applying validations to my formulas to prevent them from breaking the Query execution but still need to work on how to message the .NET application layer that the formula is invalid.
One idea is to use a Custom SQL Type, is that possible? I basically need a Custom Type that is decedent of each primitive type and behaves like NULL at the database layer, however ADO.NET would not think it is DbNull but rather another value which can flag this.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What's wrong with `TRY / CATCH`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms175976.aspx If you want to catch an error and handle the error it has to be done outside the query statement itself. It seems, that existing `TRY / CATCH` is just what you need.

Comment: You cannot use TRY CATCH in SELECT Statements inline, see the sample query results I have above, this is the expected output.

Comment: @sam360, mention the user name in the comment if you want him to receive a notification about your comment. It looks like it is not possible to get the behavior that you want in T-SQL. I would consider performing such calculations on the client side. But even in proper languages like C# if you have a loop processing row-by-row inside `try/catch` and there is an exception inside the loop, there is no way to return back into the loop and continue processing the rest of rows once the control jumps inside the `catch`.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov client-side/web server side is not an option at all. We used handle this at the client side, ran into a lot of limitations and decided to move them to SQL as part of database Views.

Comment: @sam360, you can have a look at [`SET ARITHABORT OFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190306.aspx), but it will help to ignore only overflow or divide-by-zero errors, not all possible errors in calculations. I personally would not use it.

Comment: Sounds like the best bet is to auto generate exception prevention code for as many scenarios as possible which is extremely difficult and may have performance impact because all the additional statements that needs to be built into the formula expressions.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best you are going to be to do is:

```
select T1.SubTotal,
   T2.Tax,
   T2.Tax + T1.SubTotal as Total,
   T2.LeftSide, T2.D
from Invoice as I
 cross apply (select case when NumberOfMonth = 0 then #errorvalue#  
                          else (I.UnitPrice * I.Quantity)/NumberOfMonth 
                     end) as T1(SubTotal)
...
```

and similarly for the other CROSS APPLY clauses check error conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I need to point out that this only handle one scenario and the queries are not going to hand-written and could be very complex indented statements. I need a way to control this at a higher level if possible.

Comment: "and the queries are not going to hand-written " - then I'd suggest adding that useful information to your question.

Comment: And if you're going to automatically generate the queries, then you'll have to automatically generate the error handling. There's no `ON ERROR GOTO`  in T-SQL.

Comment: How can I return an error value? it should not be Null and it should not be any other valid value.